# PHP: Compare two string message templates

Tags: php, string-comparison

I'm working on a project of Bulk sms, In india for transactional route you should register a template with Telecom operator.

Now how we identify the user sending the same template or other one ?

I did some research and written some code like below.

```
$txt1 = "TXN: <452235585> was Failed. Reference no. <452525222>";
$txt2 = "TXN: 452235585 was Failed. Reference no. 452525222. Geeglobia providing best holiday packages. Check it now";

similar_text(ltrim($txt1, '0123456789'), ltrim($txt2, '0123456789'), $percent);

echo $percent; // Gives 63.694267515924
```

Can any one gives a better idea ?

Comment: If I got that question right, you want to find out wether `$txt2` starts with `$txt1`?

Comment: Not exactly, the second should match entire string except which are in the <> brackets

Comment: Erm. ANother question (still not exactly sure what should match). The way I got it now:

Check if the second string starts with the first string, but ignore those numbers?

Comment: It should ignore the data in the angular brackets "<>"

Comment: ANd that doesn'T have to be numbers? ok, got it now I guess.

Comment: The data in that brackets was dynamic text. We can't say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the most convinient way to do this is by using regular expressions. There are two alternatives:

1) Do not specify the first string as a string but as a regexp-pattern instead, use `preg_match` to compare:

```
$txt1 = '/^TXN: .*? was Failed. Reference no. .*?$/';
$txt2 = "TXN: 452235585 was Failed. Reference no. 452525222. Geeglobia providing best holiday packages. Check it now";

$match = (preg_match($txt1, $txt2) == 1);
```

2) Convert the first string to a pattern, then do as above.

```
$txt1 = "TXN: <452235585> was Failed. Reference no. <452525222>";
$txt2 = "TXN: 452235585 was Failed. Reference no. 452525222. Geeglobia providing best holiday packages. Check it now";

$convertedTxt1 = '/^' . preg_replace("/(.*?)<.*?>/", "$1.*?", $txt1) . '$/';

$match = (preg_match($convertedTxt1, $txt2) == 1);
```

(code snippets untested)

Comment: Working a bit, but `$txt2` should not same exactly every time. The data inside the brackets may change every time. In this case if the same string its passing, Otherwise its not passing.

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi Should work that way - everything inbetween those angular barackets should be ignored. If that deosn't work, pleae provide me both strings you tried and I'll look into it again.

Comment: String1: TXN: <452235585> was <Failed>. Reference no. <452525222>
String2: TXN: 452235585 was Failed. Reference no. 452525222.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. I was un aware of the regular expression. If you don't mind could you post me some urls which you used to see.. If you do that, Very helpful to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Code edited, try now. It should work as intended.

As for regular expressions, the best reference I know is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Worked. But if you add any extra string at the end its passing. It should not accept that. For that case what we've to do bro ?

Comment: SO the strings in your question should actually NOT match? It's only considered a match if string 2 does not only start with the template, but matches the complete template?

Comment: Edited again. Note, hwoever, that if the last tihng in your template is `<...>`, it will of course still match any end, as everything can be considered "inside the bracket". There is a solution to avoid this, but only if there is NO whitespace in whatever matches those angular brackets. Is wihtespace allowed in there?

Comment: Yes we have to excuse the white spaces. Because some people will send from api's as well. So in that case.

Comment: If whitespace is allowed inside the parts that match the `<...>` parts, there is no way to prevent an `<...>` part at the end to match the anything at the end of `$str2`. Because there is no way of telling if it's supposed to be part of that or not.

Comment: Yes, we can! :) `$convertedTxt1 = '/^' . preg_replace("/(.*?)<\S*?>/", "$1.*?", $txt1) . '$/';` (all other lines unchanged, just replace that one line)

Comment: Hi dude, if there is any special charecter in the angular brackets its getting an error..

Comment: please define "special characters". and what error do you get?

Comment: `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '0' in /home/bulk18er/public_html/functions.php on line 205

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/bulk18er/public_html/functions.php:205) in /home/bulk18er/public_html/home.php on line 44`

Comment: Template used "`Aam Aadmi Party ki JanSampark Yatra VAJANA MATH CHAURAHA, SHASTRI NAGAR se 13-03-2014  ko  04:00 baje nikalegee. Meena Shivhare(member, AAP)`"

Comment: can you please post the template incuding the angular brackets? (maybe they were stripped by stockoverflow, in that case, escape them)

Comment: Template with angular brackets: `HYD GOLD: B.B(10g): <29,960> L.B(10g): <29,860> SILVER(1kg): <44,700> WRGL: <29,920/44,900> SCREEN RATE: G(10g): <29,780> S(1kg): <44,520> MADVIRAT-9000314243`

Comment: it'S the slash inside `<29,920/44,900>`. To fix it, change all slashes in the line starting with `$convertedTxt1=` to a character you don't use or escape the slash using a backslash (so it becomes `<29,920\/44,900>`).